# Azure websites auto scaling - unable to scale resource

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a website deployed into azure using azure websites. It has been running fine but for the last 2 days the autoscaling has been giving me the following error:

The autoscale engine unable to scale resource '/subscriptions/guidhere/resourceGroups/Default-Web-WestEurope/providers/microsoft.web/serverFarms/Default1' from 2 instances count to 3 instances count.

My site ie deployed with a minimum of 2 instances and increases to 3 if the CPU is greater than > 60 for a period of 15 mins.

This auto scaling has been working (I have checked the web hosting plans logs) and it has managed to increase from 2 to 3 instances and down to 2 again satisfactorily but for the last 2 days it has shows a buch of errors in the logs saying "The autoscale engine unable to scale resource ... from 2 instances count to 3 instances count".

Over the last 2 days, it has attempted to scale up about 20 times(it retries after 15/20 minutes after the last failed attempt). Out of these 20 or so times, it has failed about 17 and succeeded about 3. On a "normal" day, it scales up without any issues....

Can anyone shed anylight on this? Is this a problem with azure? Is there something I can do?

All help appreciated.

Comment: If you're seeing consistent issues with autoscale on your Website you should open a support ticket via your Azure Management Portal. No issues have been reported publicly so it may be isolated to the Websites instance you are running on.

Comment: Done exactly this and Microsoft have confirmed that there is an issue with auto scaling that is being investigated...

Comment: Ilyas, do you know if this issue has been resolved? Did they ever get back to you?

Comment: I have not had any scaling issues for a long while. If you are having scaling issues I recommend dropping microsoft azure support a tweet - they are fast at responding